# Is there software like Music Maker?

Tags: sound, music, software-recommendation

I'm looking for a tool such as Magix Music Maker for Ubuntu (and free, if possible).

I know that there is lmms, audacity, rosegarden, but I'm especially looking for a studio that includes basic sounds like drums, guitar sounds, bass (such as Magix Music Maker does).

In MMM I can pretty much click my song together using sound sets... which is awesome.:

[image]

Is there such a tool for Ubuntu?

Comment: Could you provide information as to why LMMS and Audacity aren't suitable? They feel very much 'click together' to me. Screenshots with extra description may help.

Comment: @dv3500ea: see updated question

Comment: I still don't see why LMMS won't do the job. HINT: Try clicking on 'My Samples' on the left hand side (above the star).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you mean like a piano roll editor and really accurate MIDI, LMMS should do the trick. It is in the Ubuntu repositories, but I would recommend using the version in this PPA.
https://launchpad.net/~tobydox/+archive/lmms

Also, install the appropriate sound font, and make your midi channels use it. This is also in the repositories, the package is: [fluid-soundfont-gm](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/fluid-soundfont-gm). The soundfont is located in /usr/share/sounds/sf2 when installed.

Comment: why was this voted down??? edit: good I voted it up. when voting down please include a reason (and a good one -_-)

Comment: @enchantme already mentioned LMMS in their question. I agree that LMMS is very good and I don't understand what problem enchantme has with it but they seem to be looking for something else.

Comment: They are allowed to vote me down if my answer is not sufficient. Though I indeed would like to know why so I can help them better.

Comment: @dv3500ea: my problem with LMMS is basically just one; when I doubleclick a file in the Samples browser, it copies it beside the actual track... and when I press play I naturally can't hear it. I'm not sure what to think about that.

Comment: It sounds like you need to watch [some tutorials](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=lmms+tutorial&aq=f). The interface *is* different and will take some time to learn.

Comment: Thanks for the informative answer. I used to use FL Studio and Acid on Windows and was hoping to find something similar on Linux; I installed LMMS but didn't realise there was a PPA for it.

Answer (score 7):

If you are truly interested in music creation, I would recommend [Ubuntu Studio](http://ubuntustudio.org/).  It contains pretty much everything one might need for audio work in Ubuntu.  While it includes simple programs such as [Linux Multimedia Studio](http://lmms.sourceforge.net/), it also supplies the user with [JACK](http://jackaudio.org/), usually necessary for connecting audio and running at lower latencies.

Other key programs include [Rosegarden](http://www.rosegardenmusic.com/), a MIDI composer, [Ardour](http://ardour.org/node), Linux's main Digital Audio Workstation, [Hydrogen](http://www.hydrogen-music.org/) for more composition and beats, etc.

There are also a multitude of synths, most formidably (in my opinion): [ZynAddSubFx](http://zynaddsubfx.sourceforge.net/) and [Fluidsynth](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/fluidsynth/).

If you're feeling especially bold and do not mind paying, [energyXT](http://www.energy-xt.com/) is supposed to be quite simple and great for all of the above.  However, certainly for a beginner, I would try the free, opensource programs Ubuntu offers first.

Here are a few much more general guides to linux and audio production:
[Linux Musicians](http://wiki.linuxmusicians.com/doku.php)
[Linux Audio](http://www.linuxaudio.org/)

Here is the main forum where ubuntu audio production questions and answers can be found:
[Ubuntu Studio Forum](http://ubuntuforums.org/forumdisplay.php?f=335).

Comment: This is an excellent answer. I've favourited this question so I can work through all the suggestions in your post when I find the time! I'm especially interested in hearing the synths.